# Is there any existing MEAN JS comment system available? or node modules for comment system

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, meanjs

I am developing an web app using meanjs http://meanjs.org/. But it has no comment feature for articles. Can anyone please suggest me how to develop comment system or any tutorial for it, since am very new to MEAN.

Is is it possible to integrate Disqus with meanjs?

Thanks In advance....

Comment: It is possible to integrate Disqus with anything.

Comment: @BidhanA can you give more information on how to integrate?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. You should state what you have tried and why you think it did not work. Don't just ask for code or solutions without presenting your efforts.